# consider 6 represents 6 sides of a dice, what does $x$ represent in probability generating function $x \frac{1-x^6}{1-x}$

Tags: probability

this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3614/how-to-easily-determine-the-results-distribution-for-multiple-dice) gives a formula about uniform distributed dice tossing

> The number of combinations in  throws is of course $6^$.
>
> These calculations are most readily done using the probability
>   generating function for one die

$$p(x) = x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 = x \frac{1-x^6}{1-x}$$

> (Actually this is $6$ times the pgf--I'll take care of the factor of
>   $6$ at the end.)
>
> The pgf for $n$ rolls is $p(x)^n$.

where n denotes $n$ rolls, 6 represents 6 sides of a dice.

what does $x$ represent here? does $x$ represent some particular probability, for example, $x=1/6$ represents the probability that any one of 6 possible sides?

Comment: $x$ doesn't represent something. A generating function is a way to translate the algebra with sequences to standard algebra in $\Bbb R$

Comment: It is a placeholder, it is the exponent and multiplier that contain the useful information.

Comment: @Masacroso Does $\Bbb R$ mean "the set of real numbers"?

Comment: take also a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for a more rigorous point of view. Yes, $\Bbb R$ is the set of real numbers. I mean that we use just standard sum, multiplication and division to represent transformations on the sequences. In reality we are in the algebra of formal power series (generally with real coefficients), take a look at the previous link

Answer (score 0):

The variable $x$ doesn’t represent anything in particular. It’s just the dummy variable of a formal power series that is used to encode and manipulate the probabilities.

The basic idea behind generating functions is that you encode the sequence of values that you’re interested in studying, in this case the probabilities of specific dies roll results, as the coefficients of a formal power series, called the generating function of the series. Very often, this power series has a convenient closed-form representation. The power of this representation becomes appearent when you want to manipulate the series in various ways: you can perform these manipulations “in bulk” by working with the generating function. You can get a basic overview of this subject in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function); if you want to study this subject in depth I can recommend *generatingfunctionology* by Herbert S. Wilf.

Here, we want to represent the probability mass function of a random variable $X$ that represents the result of the roll of a standard fair die. We have $\Pr(X=n)=\frac16$ for $n$ from $1$ to $6$, so we encode these probabilities as the power series $$\frac16\left(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6\right).\tag1$$ The exponent of $x$ in each term is a possible value of the random variable $X$, while the coefficient of the term is the corresponding probability. A closed-form expression for this power series is $$g(x)=\frac16{x(1-x^6)\over1-x},\tag2$$ which you can verify simplifies to (1). This is the *ordinary generating function* for the PMF of a die roll. Note that it’s not quite the same as the original series since $g$ is undefined at $1$, but we happily ignore that because we’re usually more interested in formal manipulations of these series than questions of their convergence or value.